# Set multiple cookies with the same name in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies

Is there a way to set cookies with the same name for multiple domains or paths in the same response? The following only sets the second cookie:

```
response.set_cookie("alice", "123", domain='sub.example.com')
response.set_cookie("alice", "456", domain='example.com')
```

I looked at the [Django implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/__init__.py#L634). It uses a dictionary for storing cookies:

```
self.cookies[key] = value
```

So Django cannot set multiple cookies with the same name in the same response.

Is this intended to work that way? Do you see a way to work around that limitation?

**Update**

Reported as a bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18908

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be exact answer to the question, but still.

This seems issue with the django implementation, as it is only using cookie name as a key in dict.
In real world, one can have cookies with same name with multiple values, provided either domain or path differs. I found this useful [HTTP cookies explained](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/)

More Reference:

[RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)

[Http Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've looked at the RFC but do not really see this being mentioned also it makes sense the way you explain it. Also the browsers I tested on send both cookies in the requests alice=123;alice=456; so this adds to the confusion.

Comment: @Pankrat, yes, this seems to be problem with django. check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. The blog post is really helpful. I'll file a bug for Django then.

Answer (score 3):

It does use a simple dict to store the cookie, however when rendering the cookies to the response headers django simple iterates `cookies.values()` it doesn't look at the keys.

To that end you CAN get fancy (this is python 3.5):

```
# python 3.5 specific unpacking
# Note that according to the RFC, cookies ignore the ports

hostname, *_ = request.get_host().split(':')

# set the cookie to delete
response.delete_cookie(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY,
                       domain=settings.COOKIE_DOMAIN)
# pull it out of the cookie storage
# and delete it so we can write an new one
cookie_domain_cookie = response.cookies[settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY]
del response.cookies[settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY]

# write the new cookie
response.delete_cookie(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY,
                       domain=hostname)

# do the same as we did above, probably not strictly necessary
hostname_cookie = response.cookies[settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY]
del response.cookies[settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY]

# make new keys for the cookies
cookie_domain_cookie_key = "{}:{}".format(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY, settings.COOKIE_DOMAIN)
hostname_cookie_key = "{}:{}".format(settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY, hostname)

# set them
response.cookies[cookie_domain_cookie_key] = cookie_domain_cookie
response.cookies[hostname_cookie_key] = hostname_cookie
```